# What does x:FieldModifier="Private" do and should I worry about it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, private

I'm currently checking my WPF project for Resharper messages and it tells me that every inputcontrol can be made private. When I do this, it adds `x:FieldModifier="Private"` to the control node.

I'm not that experienced with XAML. What is `x:FieldModifier`? What happens if I set it to `Private`? Is this important? Can it break stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the XAML-enabled compilers (e.g. C#, VB.NET) process an application with XAML files, much of the content of XAML files gets translated into temporary code written in the host language (e.g. C#, VB.NET). That is, the XAML files get transformed into ordinary CLI classes.

As explained in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `x:FieldModifier` directive influences the visibility of classes or members of these classes generated from XAML definitions.

In general, the principles of [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) suggest that only what is definitely needed should be visible to the outer world (outside of a given class, for example), while anything else should remain hidden (so it can be exchanged at a later point in time without breaking the public interface of a component). That is what ReSharper tries to enforce here, as input controls are often only ever accessed from within a given user control or window. Hence, the change is important for a clean code that lends itself to a high degree of maintainability.

One subtle way this can "break stuff" is that usually, XAML files are independent of the underlying programming language they are used with. Normally, you could translate the C# code of your application to another CLI-compatible language and simply keep using the XAML files (if the respective compiler also supports XAML, that is). By using the `x:FieldModifier` directive, you break that independence, as the value for that directive is language-dependent:

> The exact string you pass to specify TypeAttributes.Public versus TypeAttributes.NotPublic varies, depending on the code-behind programming language that is used.

Comment: I have a Telerik RadTileView which I dynamically populate with a custom UserControl which extends RadTileViewItem. if I set the RadTileView FieldModifier to Private, can I still refer to that RadTileView (and more specifically its items) from the custom Usercontrol using this.ParentOfType<RadTileView>()?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: I don't know the Telerik controls, so I can only describe the general conditions that have to be met in order for you to be able to still use that method: 1) The class `RadTileView` must be visible where you are invoking that method - I *suppose* ReSharper knows that it is, because that is something that can be recognized at compile-time and just making everything private without checking whether it actually needs to be public would sound somewhat insane. But, as I have never tried ReSharper, that is just a guess, as well.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: 2) That `ParentOfType` method probably uses reflection, but even then, it may have to be implemented in a way to consider non-public types and members. Whether or not that is the case is difficult to tell for me, because I only see [these Telerik docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/m_telerik_windows_controls_parentoftypeextensions_parentoftype__1.html), and they are not extensive enough to make any statement about whether the method will consider non-public identifiers.

Answer (score 8):

When XAML is converted your controls become fields in a class with the name specified with the  `Name` or `x:Name` attributes. However, these fields have a default `internal` access modifier. The purpose of `x:FieldModifier` is to allow you to control that access modifier is used. So `x:FieldModifier="Private"` actually makes the fields private.